# Python while loop not breaking with break in if loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

So the problem I have is that even after `check_win()` is true the while loop doesn't break.

This is the code:

```
board = {
    'a1': '', 'a2': '', 'a3': '',
    'b1': '', 'b2': '', 'b3': '',
    'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': ''
}

player_one = True

player_one_choice = input("Play player one: ")
if player_one_choice in board:
    board[player_one_choice] = 'x'
    player_one = False

elif player_one_choice not in board:
    print("Wrong input")
print(board)

checkwin = False


def check_win():
    """
    'x' check win logic
    """

    # Vertical check logic
    if 'x' in board['a1'] and 'x' in board['a2'] and 'x' in board['a3']:
        print("congrats x won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'x' in board['b1'] and 'x' in board['b2'] and 'x' in board['b3']:
        print("congrats x won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'x' in board['c1'] and 'x' in board['c2'] and 'x' in board['c3']:
        print("congrats x won")
        checkwin == True

    # Horizontal check logic
    elif 'x' in board['a1'] and 'x' in board['b1'] and 'x' in board['c1']:
        print("congrats x won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'x' in board['a2'] and 'x' in board['b2'] and 'x' in board['c2']:
        print("congrats x won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'x' in board['a3'] and 'x' in board['b3'] and 'x' in board['c3']:
        print("congrats x won")
        checkwin == True

    # Diagonal check logic
    elif 'x' in board['a1'] and 'x' in board['b2'] and 'x' in board['c3']:
        print("congrats x won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'x' in board['a3'] and 'x' in board['b2'] and 'x' in board['c1']:
        print("congrats x won")
        checkwin == True

    elif 'o' in board['a1'] and 'o' in board['a2'] and 'o' in board['a3']:
        print("congrats o won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'o' in board['b1'] and 'o' in board['b2'] and 'o' in board['b3']:
        print("congrats o won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'o' in board['c1'] and 'o' in board['c2'] and 'o' in board['c3']:
        print("congrats o won")
        checkwin == True

    # Horizontal check logic
    elif 'o' in board['a1'] and 'o' in board['b1'] and 'o' in board['c1']:
        print("congrats o won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'o' in board['a2'] and 'o' in board['b2'] and 'o' in board['c2']:
        print("congrats o won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'o' in board['a3'] and 'o' in board['b3'] and 'o' in board['c3']:
        print("congrats o won")
        checkwin == True

    # Diagonal check logic
    elif 'o' in board['a1'] and 'o' in board['b2'] and 'o' in board['c3']:
        print("congrats o won")
        checkwin == True
    elif 'o' in board['a3'] and 'o' in board['b2'] and 'o' in board['c1']:
        print("congrats o won")
        checkwin == True

    return


while checkwin == False:
    check_win()

    player_two_choice = input("PLay player two: ")

    if player_two_choice != 'x' and player_one_choice in board:
        board[player_two_choice] = 'o'
        player_one = True
        print(board)
    if player_two_choice != 'x' and player_one_choice not in board or player_two_choice == 'a' or player_two_choice == 'b' or player_two_choice == 'c':
        print("Wrong input")

    check_win()

    if checkwin == True:
        break

    player_one_choice = input("Play player one: ")

    if player_one_choice in board:
        board[player_one_choice] = 'x'
        player_one = False

    elif player_one_choice not in board:
        print("Wrong input")
        break

    print(board)a or player_two_choice == 'b' or player_two_choice == 'c':
        print("Wrong input")
        break

    player_one_choice = input("Play player one: ")
    print(board)
```

```
The output I have for one instance is:
```

```
Play player one: a1
{'a1': 'x', 'a2': '', 'a3': '', 'b1': '', 'b2': '', 'b3': '', 'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': ''}
PLay player two: b1
{'a1': 'x', 'a2': '', 'a3': '', 'b1': 'o', 'b2': '', 'b3': '', 'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': ''}
Play player one: a2
{'a1': 'x', 'a2': 'x', 'a3': '', 'b1': 'o', 'b2': '', 'b3': '', 'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': ''}
PLay player two: b2
{'a1': 'x', 'a2': 'x', 'a3': '', 'b1': 'o', 'b2': 'o', 'b3': '', 'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': ''}
Play player one: a3
{'a1': 'x', 'a2': 'x', 'a3': 'x', 'b1': 'o', 'b2': 'o', 'b3': '', 'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': ''}
congrats x won
PLay player two: b3
{'a1': 'x', 'a2': 'x', 'a3': 'x', 'b1': 'o', 'b2': 'o', 'b3': 'o', 'c1': '', 'c2': '', 'c3': ''}
congrats x won
Play player one: 
Wrong input

Process finished with exit code 0
```

and the input just keeps on going the while loop doesn't break

Comment: Does your `check_win()` actually return anything?

Comment: @iBug yes after clearing a lot of bugs I have one last bug, can you help me with that?

Comment: Try replacing `while checkwin == False:` with `while True:` and change `return` to `return checkwin`

Comment: Nope still not working

Comment: `return checkwin`, not `return check_win()`! Also note that there's a typo in `print(board)a' or player_two_choice .....`

Comment: @RJAdriaansen the bug is the input keeps on coming even after the 'congrats x won or o ' is displayed

Comment: @RJAdriaansen  I fixed both of those errors, still, input keeps repeating, I'll copy-paste the output in the question

Comment: As @RJAdriaansen mentioned, you need to `return checkwin`. Furthermore, inside the `checkwin` function, you should remove the `==` with `=`. Double equation mark is a comparison, the result of which is `True` or `False`, but the result is not stored anyway. Thus `checkwin = True` will actually change the state of the `checkwin` variable. Then, when calling `check_win()`, the return value shoudl actually be stored in a variable as well.

Comment: Related to the comment from @iBug. Your `check_win()` function does not return anything. The print statement you mention is just printed to the console - it is not actually returned to your function.

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen If I remove the double equation marks it says that ```checkwin``` is an unused variable

Comment: should I make the ```checkwin``` boolean varable a global variable?

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen it says ```checkwin``` is an unused variable now

Comment: wow thanks, guys you were right but I couldn't understand how to return the variable @MitchellvanZuylen so I just ditched the function and put the logic in the ```while loop``` I know it's not conventional but it works

Comment: but just for learning purposes can you show me how I could have returned that?

Comment: Can you post your updated code into the question? Then I'll update it with a function that returns it

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen no probs I fixed it